# C# Create mock of delegate static method for nUnit test

Tags: c#, delegates, nunit, static-methods, .net-core-3.1

I am working on nUnit. I need to Setup mock of a static method from same class that is under subject. I am wonder If I created mock correctly as I have defined two instances; sut of class under test and mock of same class method in objective to MockObject.Setup(..) that exist in the same class that I am trying to test. I need help to create mock of `GetNumbers()` method that is in `ProcessCalculation class`

`error`

[image]
`main`

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Testing Automation Proptype... ");

        ProcessCalculation process = new ProcessCalculation();

        process.Run();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

`Calculation`

```
public class ProcessCalculation
{
    public delegate List<int> GetNumbersPointer();

    //GetNumbersPointer getNumbersPointer = new GetNumbersPointer(GetNumbers);
  
    public GetNumbersPointer getNumbersPointer = GetNumbers;

    public void Run()
    {
        var Nos = getNumbersPointer.Invoke();

        int x = Nos[0];
        int y = Nos[1];

        var z = Add(x, y);

        Console.WriteLine("sum  "+ z);
    }

    public static int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    public static List<int> GetNumbers()
    {
        List<int> myNo = new List<int>();

        myNo.Add(32);
        myNo.Add(10);

        return myNo;
    }
}
```

`Test Class`

```
 public class Tests
{
    private readonly ProcessCalculation sut;
    private readonly Mock<ProcessCalculation> processCalculationMoq;
   

    public Tests()
    {
        sut = new ProcessCalculation();
        processCalculationMoq = new Mock<ProcessCalculation>();
    }


    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        //Arrange
        var fixture = new Fixture();

        var getNumberMoq = fixture.CreateMany<int>(2);

        processCalculationMoq.Setup(x => x.getNumbersPointer).Returns(getNumberMoq); // this throw error.. I want to mock using setup
        
        //???????????? how use delegate to mock static GetNumbers() method  
      

        //Assert
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need a mock there, as you have prepared a delegate to inject the test method. Just assign your test method to `getNumbersPointer` (make it public first)

Comment: thanks PMF, can you help me with above example. Also if I don't mock then GetNumber will return null in the test.!! ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your implementation to

```cs
public class ProcessCalculation
{
    public delegate List<int> GetNumbersPointer();

    // If InternalsVisibleTo(Unit Test assembly) is specified, this can be internal
    // Also, "new DelegateType(Target)" is not needed, the compiler inserts
    // that implicitly
    public GetNumbersPointer getNumbersPointer = GetNumbers;

    // ...
}
```

And then, in your test:

```cs
public class Tests
{
    private readonly ProcessCalculation sut;
   

    public Tests()
    {
        sut = new ProcessCalculation();
        sut.getNumbersPointer = TestGetNumbers;
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        sut.Run(); 
    }

    public static List<int> TestGetNumbers()
    {
        // Return test data
        return new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3...};
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks PMF, I have update error in my question

Comment: I want to use  like  

            processCalculationMoq.Setup(x => x.getNumbersPointer).Returns((System.Delegate)getNumberMoq);

Comment: @K.Z You can't do that. You can't set an expectation on a field. Now you could convert it to a property, but then you still have the confusion that the mock and the sut is the same object (and even the same instance!). Technically probably possible, but not a nice solution IMHO.